# zustand state not resetting

Tags: react-native, zustand

I'm trying to reset my state when pressing a button but for some reason the state just will not reset. I have a similar store elsewhere that do reset and the difference between them is the other store initialState is a nested object but I can't figure out why they behave differently.

**slice**

```js
    const initialState = {
      selected: [],
    };

    export const createMediaSelectedSlice: StateCreator<SelectedMediaSlice> = (set) => ({
      ...initialState,
      addSelection: (media: ImageProps) =>
        set((state) => ({
          selected: [...state.selected, media],
        })),
      removeSelection: (media: ImageProps) =>
        set((state) => ({
          selected: state.selected.filter(
            (item) => item.digestId !== media.digestId
          ),
        })),
      reset: () => {
        set(initialState);
      },
    });
```

**combined store**

```js
    export const useMediaStore = create<SelectedMediaSlice & MediaViewSlice>((...a) => ({
    ...createMediaSelectedSlice(...a),
    ...createMediaViewSlice(...a),
      })
    );
```

**button**

```js
    const reset = useMediaStore((state) => state.reset);
    const handlePress = () => {
        reset();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess, I could be wrong, is that both of your stores have a "reset" button (assuming). If that is the case, you are merging both stores together, and one of those "resets" will be overwritting. They share a namespace. Rename the reset. ala

```
    export const createMediaSelectedSlice: StateCreator<SelectedMediaSlice> = (set) => ({
      ...initialState,
      addSelection: (media: ImageProps) =>
        set((state) => ({
          selected: [...state.selected, media],
        })),
      removeSelection: (media: ImageProps) =>
        set((state) => ({
          selected: state.selected.filter(
            (item) => item.digestId !== media.digestId
          ),
        })),
      resetMedia: () => {
        set(initialState);
      },
    });


and use like:

    const reset = useMediaStore((state) => state.resetMedia);
    const handlePress = () => {
        reset();
    }
```